# stdbool.h: #define true true

Tags: c++, gcc, c++98

`stdbool.h` contains this code:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
/* Defining these macros in C++98 is a GCC extension.  */
#define bool    bool
#define false   false
#define true    true
#endif
```

Why does gcc need to redefine standard C++ types?

Comment: The real question is why you would ever include this header in a C++ file. The whole thing seems like it should be excluded if `__cplusplus` is defined. Maybe these definitions are there for backwards compatibility with C programs and/or older versions of the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Although `#define fnord fnord` won't generally change the way the identifier `fnord` is processed, it will cause `#ifdef fnord` to report the macro as defined.  If other code might do something like

```
#ifndef true
#define true 1
#endif
```

Having a `#define true true` would cause such conditional definition to be skipped.